# what is the ideal directory structure of a ruby application

Tags: ruby, newgem

what is the ideal directory structure of a ruby application.

I want it to be deployed on EC2. It should have Gemfile and Rake file for executing rake tasks.

It should contain a lib file for utilities.

Should I just be using the command

newgem --simple test

Comment: Depends on the application. But if you're using Rails or Sinatra, I highly recommend deploying to Heroku: you get EC2 and really, really easy deployment.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler).
'bundle gem simple_test' works great for me.

```
$ bundle gem simple_test
  create  simple_test/Gemfile
  create  simple_test/Rakefile
  create  simple_test/.gitignore
  create  simple_test/simple_test.gemspec
  create  simple_test/lib/simple_test.rb
  create  simple_test/lib/simple_test/version.rb
  Initializating git repo in /Users/sean/dev/foo/simple_test
$
```

Comment: Cool thanks! I think this is good enough. So I can have all my source code inside lib directory right?

Comment: @sarvesh: In this template, your code goes in lib/simple_test.  Though if you have C code, it's traditional to put it in an ext folder.